# Python regex: Explain why expression not matching

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am using `regex` library to find words that are in between specific other words, for example, I want to match "world" if and only if a greeting precedes it and punctuation follows. To avoid matching word prefixes and suffixes, I added the additional condition `[^a-zA-Z]`. However, once I add these, `regex` cannot match the word anymore:

```
>>> import regex

>>> pat = regex.compile("(?<=[^a-zA-Z](hello|hi)\s+)world(?=\s*[!?.][^a-zA-Z])")

>>> list(pat.finditer("hello world!"))
[]

>>> pat = regex.compile("(?<=\b(hello|hi)\s+)world(?=\s*[!?.]\b)")

>>> list(pat.finditer("hello world!"))
[]

>>> pat = regex.compile("(?<=(hello|hi)\s+)world(?=\s*[!?.])")

>>> list(pat.finditer("hello world!"))
[<regex.Match object; span=(6, 11), match='world'>]
```

How can this be explained? How to make sure to match whole words in the look ahead and behind sections?

Comment: does it match `" hello world!"` (with a preceding space)? `[^a-zA-Z]` has width 1, so I think the string can't start with `hello` or `hi`. That said, i've never worked with the `regex` module - only `re` - so can't speak for that package.

Comment: It indeed does match `" hello world! "`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try boundaries instead `pat = regex.compile("(?<=\\b(hello|hi)\\s+)world(?=\\b\\s*[!?.])")`

Comment: @Daniel That would work for the look-behind, too. But the look-ahead doesn't work as intended, because `"hello world!x"` shouldn't match.

Comment: If you want to debug a regex, [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is one of best tools currently available, though a web search will turn up more. See also "[How do you debug a regex? \[closed\]](/q/2348694/90527)", "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when using `(?<=` and `(?=` there has to be present on the left and right what you specify.

Note that there is no word boundary after `[!?.]\b` when there is not a word character following any of the punctuation chars.

You could write the pattern as:

```
(?<=\b(?:hello|hi)\s+)world(?=\s*[!?.](?!\S))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is

  - `\b(?:hello|hi)\s+` Match either the word `hello` or `hi` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `)` Close lookbhehind
- `world` Match literally
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that to the right is

  - `\s*[!?.]` Match optional whitespace chars and one of `!` `?` `.`
  - `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right
- `)` Close the lookahead

Or asserting a whitespace boundary to the left instead of the word boundary:

```
(?<=(?<!\S)(?:hello|hi)\s+)world(?=\s*[!?.](?!\S))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8BTSuF/1)

Answer (score 0):

As correctly mentioned by [@Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3888719/michael-delgado), the width was the problem. The following does the trick:

```
>>> import regex

>>> pat = regex.compile("(?<=([^a-zA-Z]|^)(hello|hi)\s+)world(?=\s*[!?.]($|[^a-zA-Z]))")

>>> list(pat.finditer("hello world!"))
[<regex.Match object; span=(6, 11), match='world'>]

>>> list(pat.finditer("hello world!x"))
[]

>>> list(pat.finditer("xhello world!"))
[]
```